# Soot : no callgraph present in Scene ! Failed to apply jb

Tags: java, soot

Using Soot, I am trying to build the call graph. To my knowledge, the problem was that, dealing with APIs, there are no main methods to be used as entrypoints.
I check more thoroughly what Soot was loading. The classes used are "correctly loaded" (I print their list from `Scene.v().getClasses()` and it shows the proper classes from the project (source and test-source).

Now, Soot keep rising the same exception when asking for a call graph with `Scene.v().getCallGraph()` :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No call graph present in Scene. Maybe you want Whole Program mode (-w).
```

I thus tried to add entry points manually, looking for methods in the test-suite to be used on that purpose. I discovered that, if the classes are loaded, their methods are not. This is the snippet I use though, found on Soot's tutorial to load classes methods :

```
    SootClass c = Scene.v().loadClassAndSupport(name);
    c.setApplicationClass();
    Iterator<SootMethod> mi = c.getMethods().iterator();
    while (mi.hasNext()) {
        SootMethod sm = (SootMethod)mi.next();
        if (sm.isConcrete()) {
            sm.retrieveActiveBody();
        }
    }
```

But `c.getMethods()` return no methods...
More, the call `sm.retrieveActiveBody();` rise an exception :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to apply jb to <com.[...classified...].resource.VoidResource: void <init>()>
    at soot.asm.AsmMethodSource.getBody(AsmMethodSource.java:1911)
    at soot.SootMethod.getBodyFromMethodSource(SootMethod.java:126)
    at soot.SootMethod.retrieveActiveBody(SootMethod.java:385)
    at ca.umontreal.iro.soot.CallGraphExample.loadClass(CallGraphExample.java:204)
    at ca.umontreal.iro.soot.CallGraphExample.loadClasses(CallGraphExample.java:139)
    at ca.umontreal.iro.soot.CallGraphExample.loadClasses(CallGraphExample.java:157)
    at ca.umontreal.iro.soot.CallGraphExample.loadClasses(CallGraphExample.java:157)
    at ca.umontreal.iro.soot.CallGraphExample.loadClasses(CallGraphExample.java:157)
    at ca.umontreal.iro.soot.CallGraphExample.loadClasses(CallGraphExample.java:157)
    at ca.umontreal.iro.soot.CallGraphExample.loadClasses(CallGraphExample.java:157)
    at ca.umontreal.iro.soot.CallGraphExample.loadClasses(CallGraphExample.java:157)
    at ca.umontreal.iro.soot.CallGraphExample.main(CallGraphExample.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: RefType java.lang.InstantiationError not loaded. If you tried to get the RefType of a library class, did you call loadNecessaryClasses()? Otherwise please check Soot's classpath.
    at soot.Scene.getRefType(Scene.java:916)
    at soot.toolkits.exceptions.ThrowableSet$Manager.<init>(ThrowableSet.java:213)
    at soot.Singletons.soot_toolkits_exceptions_ThrowableSet_Manager(Singletons.java:1829)
    at soot.toolkits.exceptions.ThrowableSet$Manager.v(ThrowableSet.java:277)
    at soot.toolkits.exceptions.UnitThrowAnalysis.<init>(UnitThrowAnalysis.java:215)
    at soot.toolkits.exceptions.UnitThrowAnalysis.<init>(UnitThrowAnalysis.java:231)
    at soot.Singletons.soot_toolkits_exceptions_UnitThrowAnalysis(Singletons.java:1843)
    at soot.toolkits.exceptions.UnitThrowAnalysis.v(UnitThrowAnalysis.java:246)
    at soot.Scene.getDefaultThrowAnalysis(Scene.java:1324)
    at soot.jimple.toolkits.scalar.UnreachableCodeEliminator.internalTransform(UnreachableCodeEliminator.java:78)
    at soot.BodyTransformer.transform(BodyTransformer.java:54)
    at soot.Transform.apply(Transform.java:105)
    at soot.JimpleBodyPack.applyPhaseOptions(JimpleBodyPack.java:62)
    at soot.JimpleBodyPack.internalApply(JimpleBodyPack.java:105)
    at soot.Pack.apply(Pack.java:125)
    at soot.asm.AsmMethodSource.getBody(AsmMethodSource.java:1909)
    ... 11 more
```

This applies to almost all classes (test-classes excepted).
What am I doing wrong ? Why are the methods rejected ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the command-line parameter -w as the error message suggest?

Comment: lol, oui. Programmatically, it is called `set_whole_program(boolean)`

Comment: I should also mention that the same commandline executed via `Options.v().Main()` or in the windows command produces a good set of jimple files (I am not sure their methods are ALL (exhaustively) full, but they look fine.

Answer (score 0):

dude.
You can have a try to write this:

```java
Options.v().set_whole_program(true);
Scene.v().loadNecessaryClasses();
PackManager.v().runPacks();
```

lol maybe it helps you.